# MySQL: How to retrieve maximum value supported by a numeric data type?

Tags: mysql

Besides using MySQL's `DESCRIBE` syntax and parsing the `Type` column, is there any way to programmatically determine what's the largest integer that can be stored in a given `INT` column and its varieties? (e.g. `TINYINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, etc.)  I'd simply store a hard-coded table, except that my columns use custom lengths like `TINYINT(2)` and `MEDIUMINT(5)`.

I ask because I'm thinking of writing a cron job to warn me when my various auto-incrementing integer-based ID columns approach their maximum values, so I can reduce the risk of integer overruns.

**Edit**

I see this was kind of a dumb question.  As was pointed out to me, the custom lengths don't affect the maximum integer values that those columns can store.  So if I wanted to write the script, I can hard-code the maximum integer sizes given in the MySQL manual. As to whether this script is the best way to handle things, that's debatable.

Comment: Why would you ever use variants like that? If you're worried about roll-overs, your datatype is *way* too small.

Comment: Programmatically? Just [read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Use INT(11) and by the time you get to this number, I'm sure you would have solved this problem

Comment: Those "custom lengths" are merely display width for `ZEROFILL` padding.  They do not affect the range of values that can be stored in the column.

Comment: @Ibu Why create the overhead?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it won't be overhead if he is expecting big numbers

Comment: @Ibu Then OP shouldn't be using `tinyint`.

Comment: Wow, quick replies everyone.  Thanks.  I take it the answer to my question is "no", and that I'd have to parse `DESCRIBE` output or switch to using much larger `INT`-type columns.  I'll have to think more about what works best for my situation.

Comment: Oh.  Okay, thanks `eggyal` for pointing out that the custom lengths don't affect the max integer values. Learned something today!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom lengths DO NOT affect the max value, in the case of INTs they are merely a hint for visually outputting/displaying the value AND are ONLY used when autofill leading zeroes is being used.

Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817537/330315 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634151/330315 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432037/330315 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048597/330315  (tnx to a_horse_with_no_name for once giving me these links.)